# sending exit code without exiting the script

Tags: powershell

suppose i have 2 servers. lets say i am performing an operation on these 2 servers sequentially (for loop) and i pass an exit code in 3 scenarios:

```
2 servers success: exit 0
2 servers fail: exit 1
1 server fail 1 server success: exit 0
```

currently, i use this `exit 1` to return an exit code to AutoSys (where we have automated jobs) to indicate failure if something fails, and `exit 0` to indicate success.

however, this exits the script as well, so wherever i have this command the script would stop executing.

this is fine in the current 3 scenarios i have, however, we would like to change the last scenario  `1 server fail 1 server success: exit 0` to  `1 server fail 1 server success: exit 1`  in which if one server fails, even if the other server succeeds, send failure code.

this may work generally if the first server succeeds and the 2nd one fails because that is the end of the script anyways so its fine to exit. but in the case where the FIRST server fails but there is YET another server to run the operation on, it will exit without letting the operation to run on server2.

so i need a way to exit 1 (fail) WITHOUT ending the script operation

Comment: Can you just store the value in a variable and exit at the end of the script?

Comment: @RyanBemrose i dont think so...but let me try

Comment: @RyanBemrose just tried it. it doesnt work. wherever exit is it will immediately exit, regardless if you set it to a variable

Comment: I would say to replace the `Exit 1` section of both servers to something like `$Server1Failed = $true` and `$Server2Failed = $true`. Then, at the end of the script, have an if statement like this `if ($Server1Failed -or $Server2Failed) {Exit 1} else {Exit 0}.

Comment: @kuzimoto looks like ill have to change the structure of my script....ahhhh i hoped thered be another easy alternative

Comment: Yeah sorry :/ I just don't think there's an alternative since Exit will just... exit... haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do things like this in .bat files.  You can tell by the exit number which job had an error.  It's kind of like setting bits in an integer.

```
$err = 0

# 1st job
if (-not $?) { $err += 1 }

# 2nd job
if (-not $?) { $err += 2 }

# 3rd job
if (-not $?) { $err += 4 }

exit $err
```

Maybe you can do something with $error, but it contains the errors of all scripts run within a powershell process.

Here's another method I've recently been using.  You can't tell which command made the error, but you can tell how many errors there are in the whole script.

```
$errorcount = $Error.Count

Get-Childitem foo1
Get-Childitem foo2
Get-Childitem foo3

exit $Error.Count - $errorcount
```

Then if all 3 didn't exist, $LASTEXITCODE would be 3.  Or %errorlevel%.